# Get html from backend (C#) after page is rendered with Vue

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

How do I get the html from a page after Vue has rendered the page.

I have tried the HttpClient, but it get's the html before Vue has rendered the page and therefore the div html element containing the Vue content is empty.

It is needed to generate a PDF from the html content.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://www.mypage.com");
}
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Sounds like you need something that executes the javascript like Selenium.

Comment: The server will not know anything about what vue has done on the client browser. A quick google found [this](https://medium.com/@toakshay.official/vue-js-generate-pdf-from-html-f095cf72bff4) which might be useful.